# RSA Encryption using modulus and exponent in Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm currently doing RSA encryption on Java and I have to use private and public modulus for the encryption. I currently Have the following:

```
private void createPublicKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        String publicModulus = "d2c34017ef94f8ab6696dae66e3c0d1ad186bbd9ce4461b68d7cd017c15bda174045bfef36fbf048" +
                "73cfd6d09e3806af3949f99c3e09d6d3c37f6398d8c63f9a3e39b78a187809822e8bcf912f4c44a8" +
                "92fe6a65a477ddea9582738317317286a2610ba30b6b090c3b8c61ffb64207229b3f01afe928a960" +
                "c5a44c24b26f5f91";

        BigInteger keyInt = new BigInteger(publicModulus, 16);
        BigInteger exponentInt = new BigInteger("10001", 16);
        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpeck = new RSAPublicKeySpec(keyInt, exponentInt);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpeck);

    }

private void createPrivateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        String privateModulus = "6c97ab6369cf00dd174bacd7c37e6f661d04e5af10670d4d88d30148ec188e63227b8dac0c517cf9" +
                "67aa73cd23684c9165dc269f091bfab33b6c5c7db95b54130e348255c30aaaac1c7f09ef701e0d6f" +
                "6dc142d2e4ed78466cc104e28d50be7adf3863afc021dbdd8b5f0b968b7cd965242c7d8d4b32ee84" +
                "0fac3cad134344c1";
        BigInteger privateModulusInt = new BigInteger(privateModulus, 16);
        BigInteger exponentInt = new BigInteger("10001", 16);
        RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(privateModulusInt, exponentInt);
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
    }
```

In the main method I have the following:

```
        createPrivateKey();
        createPublicKey();

        String data = "12";

        Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedData = cipher1.doFinal(data.getBytes());

        Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,privateKey);
        byte[] decryptedData = cipher2.doFinal(encryptedData);
        System.out.println(new String(decryptedData));
```

In the console I get the following: ���.7���p;%kV�9y���xa�ɼ{ and not `"12"` If I make the `String data = "12345";`, I then get: `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Message is larger than modulus`

Firstly why is the encryption and decryption not working? Why am I not getting back `"12"`. Secondly why can I not have data be greater than 2 characters?

Note I'm using the following [website](http://nmichaels.org/rsa.py) to get the modulus and exponent values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error creating the private key. You are providing the public exponent instead of private and (as commented @dave_thomsom_085) private exponent instead of modulus

Change `createPrivateKey()` with

```
private static PrivateKey createPrivateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        String publicModulus = "d2c34017ef94f8ab6696dae66e3c0d1ad186bbd9ce4461b68d7cd017c15bda174045bfef36fbf048" +
                "73cfd6d09e3806af3949f99c3e09d6d3c37f6398d8c63f9a3e39b78a187809822e8bcf912f4c44a8" +
                "92fe6a65a477ddea9582738317317286a2610ba30b6b090c3b8c61ffb64207229b3f01afe928a960" +
                "c5a44c24b26f5f91";
        String privateExponent = "6c97ab6369cf00dd174bacd7c37e6f661d04e5af10670d4d88d30148ec188e63227b8dac0c517cf9" +
                "67aa73cd23684c9165dc269f091bfab33b6c5c7db95b54130e348255c30aaaac1c7f09ef701e0d6f" +
                "6dc142d2e4ed78466cc104e28d50be7adf3863afc021dbdd8b5f0b968b7cd965242c7d8d4b32ee84" +
                "0fac3cad134344c1";
        BigInteger privateExponenInt = new BigInteger(privateExponent, 16);
        BigInteger keyInt = new BigInteger(publicModulus, 16);
        RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(keyInt, privateExponenInt);
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return factory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
    }
```

Also you should not use raw RSA without padding for security reasons. Use `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` or the new OAEP padding `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding`

According to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/9265/112160) you can encrypt with `PKCS1Padding` data up to 11 bytes less than the key size. [and using OAEP](http://info.townsendsecurity.com/bid/29195/how-much-data-can-you-encrypt-with-rsa-keys) it must be less than the size of the key modulus – 41

Then, using your 1024 bits key:

- PKCS1: `(1024 bits / 8) - 11 = 117 bytes`
- OAEP: `(1024 bits / 8) - 42 = 86 bytes`

Also is recommended to use CRT instead of private exponent directly

```
RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec privateKeySpec = 
    new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent, privateExponent, primeP, primeQ, primeExpP, primeExpQ, crtCoefficient);
```

Comment: public exponent instead of private _AND_ private exponent instead of modulus. There is no such thing a public modulus or private modulus in RSA; there is one modulus with public and private exponents. And using the private exponent directly, instead of CRT, is about 30 years out of date. And that website is wrong about its historical note as well. In short, don't rely on it.

Comment: Accurate diagnosis @dave_thompson_085, I have added your recommendations. Thanks