# How to create RSA PrivateKey from string with RSAPrivateKeySpec class in Java?

Tags: java, rsa

I have the below information and want to generate a public and private key in RSA (Java).

```
    String pubKey = "MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJXFRUWMDJZ+moC/VbcAXoY5dDxOruwI2B+B+YZRHSRRTKPyd9v0HTqdLeVgufLu/cSxlZAKtZDp9mfgyNdbY9ECAwEAAQ==";
    String privKey = "MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAlcVFRYwMln6agL9VtwBehjl0PE6u7AjYH4H5hlEdJFFMo/J32/QdOp0t5WC58u79xLGVkAq1kOn2Z+DI11tj0QIDAQABAkBC1Bp71OkNAgL47edWWADVja9y9X0R70RYkst/hpQlTrjN4QxzN4k4gCqqdFkno2LfacRO7igMQuVEmYujfkbNAiEA/lU1CyW9J65FXSObsBLxqlNpFw79B2EKUkT6o7b2Ez8CIQCWwJlIyDaoXt7CrvTrPDpok7U93ZKmDPiRjjXDPsGU7wIhAJ6pITIXFO2QNg1ojVNGPiR3bHPKEedsjjfMeF9xYAmZAiAQnfpHg4pC1PJJE2/73g+yJ1X7E8ludE+R+9MBSpGcEQIgBWaVSyTx4e+gSulT93vnMpVsYmiwe53e5t4Uxs+cgSE=";
    String nModulusPublic = "AJXFRUWMDJZ-moC_VbcAXoY5dDxOruwI2B-B-YZRHSRRTKPyd9v0HTqdLeVgufLu_cSxlZAKtZDp9mfgyNdbY9E=";
    String eExponentPublic = "AQAB";
    String nModulusPrivate = "AJXFRUWMDJZ-moC_VbcAXoY5dDxOruwI2B-B-YZRHSRRTKPyd9v0HTqdLeVgufLu_cSxlZAKtZDp9mfgyNdbY9E=";
    String eExponentPrivate = "QtQae9TpDQIC-O3nVlgA1Y2vcvV9Ee9EWJLLf4aUJU64zeEMczeJOIAqqnRZJ6Ni32nETu4oDELlRJmLo35GzQ==";
```

These are main Encryption and decryption functions :

```
static String Decrypt(String encodedString,PrivateKey privKey) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherInstancename);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString));
        return new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception err) {
        return err.fillInStackTrace().toString();
    }
}

static String Encrypt(String encodedString,PublicKey pubKey) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherInstancename);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] plainBytes = new String(encodedString).getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
        String encryptedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherData);
        return encryptedString;
    } catch (Exception err) {
        return err.fillInStackTrace().toString();
    }
}
```

If I create PrivateKey and PublicKey with below function everything works great:

```
 static PrivateKey firstPrivateKey(String privateKeyStr) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec specPrivate = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey fileGeneratedPrivateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(specPrivate);
    RSAPrivateKey rsaPrv  = (RSAPrivateKey)(fileGeneratedPrivateKey);
    return  rsaPrv;
}
 static PublicKey firstPublicKey(String publicKeyStr) throws Exception {
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    X509EncodedKeySpec specPublic = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    PublicKey fileGeneratedPublicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(specPublic);
    RSAPublicKey rsaPub  = (RSAPublicKey)(fileGeneratedPublicKey);
    return  rsaPub;
}
```

But I want to create them by this way with below function but decryption does not work:

```
 static PublicKey secondPublicKey(String publicKString,String publicExponentStr) throws Exception {
    byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKString);
    byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicExponentStr);
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

    RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);
    return pubKey;
}

static PrivateKey secondPrivateKey(String privateKString,String privateExponentStr) throws Exception {
    byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKString);
    byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateExponentStr);
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

    RSAPrivateKeySpec privSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus,exponent);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privKey = fact.generatePrivate(privSpec);

    return privKey;
}
```

Using firstPrivateKey and firstPublicKey key generators and work nice:

```
   String a = Encrypt("test",firstPrivateKey(pubKey));
   String b = Decrypt(a, firstPublicKey(privKey));
   System.out.println(b);
```

Using second functions and does not work:

```
 String a = Encrypt("test",secondPublicKey(pubKey,eExponentPublic));
 String b = Decrypt(a, secondPrivateKey(privKey,eExponentPrivate));
 System.out.println(b);
```

What's the problem with secondPublicKey and secondPrivateKey functions?

**Update:**

I generate all keys and Modulus from this code, It seems my decoding is not ok:

```
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    // RSAKeyGenParameterSpec spec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1024, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4);
    kpg.initialize( 512 );
    KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    String publicKeyStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(kp.getPublic().getEncoded());
    String privateKeyStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(kp.getPrivate().getEncoded());

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    X509EncodedKeySpec specPublic = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    PublicKey fileGeneratedPublicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(specPublic);
    RSAPublicKey rsaPub  = (RSAPublicKey)(fileGeneratedPublicKey);

    keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec specPrivate = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    PrivateKey fileGeneratedPrivateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(specPrivate);
    RSAPrivateKey rsaPrv  = (RSAPrivateKey)(fileGeneratedPrivateKey);


    BigInteger publicKeyModulus = rsaPub.getModulus();
    BigInteger publicKeyExponent  = rsaPub.getPublicExponent();
    BigInteger privateKeyModulus = rsaPrv.getModulus();
    BigInteger privateKeyExponent  = rsaPrv.getPrivateExponent();


    String nModulusPublic=Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(publicKeyModulus.toByteArray());
    String eExponentPublic=Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(publicKeyExponent.toByteArray());
    String nModulusPrivate=Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(privateKeyModulus.toByteArray());
    String eExponentPrivate=Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(privateKeyExponent.toByteArray());

    System.out.println(publicKeyStr);
    System.out.println(privateKeyStr);
    System.out.println( nModulusPublic);
    System.out.println(eExponentPublic);
    System.out.println( nModulusPrivate);
    System.out.println(eExponentPrivate);
```

Comment: It's better to generate a RSAPrivateCrtKey and not a PrivateKey as the other parameters would be missing in your private key and cn cause problems in the future. So you need the data from "primeP, primeQ, primeExpP, primeExpQ, crtCoefficient" as well. See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41587832/8166854. It seems you are working on a C# to Java project but you already have the missing data in your private key as xml-strings on C#-side :-)

Comment: the encoding of the module and the exponent are weird. It is not base64 because of the `-` and` _` characters, which indicate that base64urlencoding is being used, but it should not end with `=`. You can try with `Base64.getUrlDecoder()` instead of `base64.getDecoder()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A related public and private key have the same modulus. Therefore the distinction between `nModulusPublic` and `nModulusPrivate` is actually not necessary (unlike the public and private exponent).

`secondPublicKey()` and `secondPrivateKey()` expect the modulus (`nModulusPublic` or the identical `nModulusPrivate`) as first argument. Instead, the entire key (`pubKey` or `privKey`) is passed, which causes the error. If the modulus is passed instead, it works.

By the way, modulus and exponent are Base64url encoded and must first be converted to the standard Base64 encoding (`-` -> `+` and `_` -> `/`). Alternatively the Base64url decoder can be used in `secondPublicKey()` or `secondPrivateKey()` (`Base64.getUrlDecoder()`).

Since the two public or private keys are identical (only with different formats) any public/private key combination is possible for encryption/deryption:

```
String pubKey = "MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJXFRUWMDJZ+moC/VbcAXoY5dDxOruwI2B+B+YZRHSRRTKPyd9v0HTqdLeVgufLu/cSxlZAKtZDp9mfgyNdbY9ECAwEAAQ==";
String privKey = "MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAlcVFRYwMln6agL9VtwBehjl0PE6u7AjYH4H5hlEdJFFMo/J32/QdOp0t5WC58u79xLGVkAq1kOn2Z+DI11tj0QIDAQABAkBC1Bp71OkNAgL47edWWADVja9y9X0R70RYkst/hpQlTrjN4QxzN4k4gCqqdFkno2LfacRO7igMQuVEmYujfkbNAiEA/lU1CyW9J65FXSObsBLxqlNpFw79B2EKUkT6o7b2Ez8CIQCWwJlIyDaoXt7CrvTrPDpok7U93ZKmDPiRjjXDPsGU7wIhAJ6pITIXFO2QNg1ojVNGPiR3bHPKEedsjjfMeF9xYAmZAiAQnfpHg4pC1PJJE2/73g+yJ1X7E8ludE+R+9MBSpGcEQIgBWaVSyTx4e+gSulT93vnMpVsYmiwe53e5t4Uxs+cgSE=";
String nModulusPublic = "AJXFRUWMDJZ-moC_VbcAXoY5dDxOruwI2B-B-YZRHSRRTKPyd9v0HTqdLeVgufLu_cSxlZAKtZDp9mfgyNdbY9E=".replace("-", "+").replace("_","/");
String eExponentPublic = "AQAB".replace("-", "+").replace("_","/");
String nModulusPrivate = "AJXFRUWMDJZ-moC_VbcAXoY5dDxOruwI2B-B-YZRHSRRTKPyd9v0HTqdLeVgufLu_cSxlZAKtZDp9mfgyNdbY9E=".replace("-", "+").replace("_","/");
String eExponentPrivate = "QtQae9TpDQIC-O3nVlgA1Y2vcvV9Ee9EWJLLf4aUJU64zeEMczeJOIAqqnRZJ6Ni32nETu4oDELlRJmLo35GzQ==".replace("-", "+").replace("_","/");    

String a, b;

// first/first
a = Encrypt("test", firstPublicKey(pubKey));
b = Decrypt(a, firstPrivateKey(privKey));
System.out.println(b);

// second/second
a = Encrypt("test", secondPublicKey(nModulusPublic, eExponentPublic));
b = Decrypt(a, secondPrivateKey(nModulusPrivate, eExponentPrivate));
System.out.println(b);

// first/second
a = Encrypt("test", firstPublicKey(pubKey));
b = Decrypt(a, secondPrivateKey(nModulusPrivate, eExponentPrivate));
System.out.println(b);

// second/first
a = Encrypt("test", secondPublicKey(nModulusPublic, eExponentPublic));
b = Decrypt(a, firstPrivateKey(privKey));
System.out.println(b);
```

Note that there is a typo in the posted code: `Encrypt` is used in combination with `firstPrivateKey()` and `Decrypt` in combination with `firstPublicKey()`.

Comment: Your comment has been removed though, but nevertheless the following information concerning your update-section: You use two different encodings: _Base64 (standard)_ because of `Base64.getEncoder()` and _Base64url_ because of `Base64.getUrlEncoder()`. _Base64url_ uses the characters `-` and `_` instead of `+` and `/`, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table). I would recommend to apply the same encoding (unless you have special reasons for using different encodings).